# How to stop only first li from scrolling in ul li list with overflow auto?

Tags: html, css

I have made simple ul li list with ul having specific max-height and overflow: auto so that it can get scrolling if a long list is available. but I am trying to fix the first li and want to scroll all other li.

```css
.account-selector__listing.dropdown.is-open {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 22rem;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="account-selector__listing ng-scope dropdown is-open">
  <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
    //want to fix this li and dont want to scroll this
  </li>
  <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
    //some content
  </li>
  <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
    //should scroll
  </li>
  <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
    //should scroll
  </li>
  <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
    //should scroll
  </li>
  <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
    //should scroll
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is there anything in CSS that I can fix the first li and can scroll all other vertically? like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a container element around your `ul`, you can achieve this effect using `position`.

- Set the container element to `position: relative` and give it top padding.
- Set `li:first-child` to `position: absolute`
- Set the `ul` to `position: static` so that `li:first-child` gets its positioning from the container element instead of the `ul`

```css
.ulOuter {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.account-selector__listing.dropdown.is-open {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    max-height: 120px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: static;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px inset #eeeeee;
}

.account-selector__listing.dropdown.is-open li:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ulOuter">
<ul class="account-selector__listing ng-scope dropdown is-open" >
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //want to fix this li and dont want to scroll this
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //some content 
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //should scroll 
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //should scroll 
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //should scroll 
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //should scroll 
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //should scroll 
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //should scroll 
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //should scroll 
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //should scroll 
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //should scroll 
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.account-selector__listing.dropdown.is-open > li:first-child {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

try this, if it doesn't fix the issue,let me know.please do comment it.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for help but unfortunately this solution is not working as scroll is applying to whole ul and as per your solution it might restrict scroll inside first li

Answer (score 0):

You can have it with two ul.. Let me know if two ul work.
you can put your max height in here.

```css
ul:nth-of-type(2) {
 max-height: 80px;
 overflow: auto;
}
.account-selector__item {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="account-selector__listing ng-scope dropdown is-open" >
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
           //fixed contnent
</ul>
<ul class="account-selector__listing ng-scope dropdown is-open" >
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
            //scroll content 
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //scroll content 
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //scroll scroll 
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //scroll scroll 
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //scroll scroll 
 </li>
           <li class="account-selector__item ng-scope active dropdown">
                //scroll scroll 
 </li>
</ul>
```